# Sudden Lack of Style.css Ghost site

Tags: html, css, http-status-code-404

I was editing style.css and a header.hbs, and everything worked fine. Then later it seemed that it completely lost the ability to find style.css. The file didn't move, it still has the same permissions, and appears to contain no errors according to CSS Lint and CSS Validator. Here are the files, and I've left the site up here:
electronomy.net

style.css
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8664258

All of the other css files in that folder are found, but not the style.css. I'm baffled. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If the file is indeed missing (yes, it does give a 404), how can you see that it still has the same permissions? How are you looking at the file when you check those permissions?

Comment: Sftp into the web server

Comment: Hm... so if you look at the directory with ftp, all the files are there normally, but with http, http://electronomy.net/assets/css/style.css isn't present, although other files like http://electronomy.net/assets/css/normalize.css are. Hrm... no, sorry, I don't have any ideas. Interesting problem though!